# How to use a column value in if condition?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

> ```
> Appr_ID   Status
> ----------------
> Null      1
> 3         2
> 4         3
> NULL      4
> 7         5
> NULL      6
> ```

I've two columns in a table, which have values as shown above.

I need to write a Stored Procedure so that whenever `Appr_ID` column has a Not Null value, it would fetch and display data from certain tables with some multiple joins.

When `Appr_ID` column is NULL, again it will have to use some different conditions to fetch and display the data.

My problem is, when I try to use `if`-`else` statement, it is not possible to use a column value as a condition in if statement, like

```
If Appr_ID is Null then
  Select...
Else
  Select...
```

So, please suggest alternate ideas to accomplish the scenario.

Thanks in advance, Krishna

Comment: can you provide more information..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it in one statement do both joins and then use CASE .... WHEN to decide which columns to use in the output.

For a brief example of what I mean:-

```
SELECT a.*, CASE WHEN a.somefield IS NULL THEN b.somefield ELSE c.someotherfield END AS OutputField
FROM SomeTable a
LEFT OUTER JOIN SecondTable b ON a.somefield = b.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ThirdTable c ON a.somefield = c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `CASE` statement.

Eg:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN Appr_ID IS NULL THEN (
      SELECT somevalue 
      FROM sometable 
           JOIN ... 
           JOIN ... 
      WHERE something=something)
    ELSE (SELECT somevalue 
          FROM someothertable 
               JOIN ... 
               JOIN ...  
          WHERE something=something)
  END as Your_Result_ColumnName

FROM
  YourTableWithApprIDInIt
```

This will be quite efficient if each sub-query is basically returning the same result regardless of some value in the main `YourTableWithApprIDInIt` table (eg `Appr_ID` iself).  This is because that sub-query won't actually be executed over and over for each row; it's result would be cached by the DBMS and re-used for each row.

But if the subquery *depends* on `Appr_ID` (such that each subquery needs to be re-executed on each row), then rather than using sub-queries, you would probably use a `JOIN` instead (in your main `FROM` clause).

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN a.Appr_ID IS NULL THEN b.somevalue 
    ELSE c.somevalue
  END as Your_Result_ColumnName

FROM
  YourTableWithApprIDInIt a
  JOIN sometable b ON a.x = b.x
  JOIN ... ON ..

  JOIN someothertable c ON a.x = c.x
  JOIN ... ON ..
```

You *could* still use subqueries in this scenario if you wanted, but it might not be so clean (and will possibly be less efficient, as the DBMS will be handling multiple logically disjointed result sets - although I say "possibly" because the DBMS may optimise this properly).

I'd test under your specific scenario to see if one approach yields better results than the other.  If performance is even a factor.

---

**Update:**

In the case where you need to select *multiple* values depending on your `Appr_ID` value being null or not, then you'd need to repeat the `case` statement for each column in your main query, eg:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN Appr_ID IS NULL THEN (
      SELECT somevalue_1
      FROM sometable_1
           JOIN ... 
           JOIN ... 
      WHERE something=something)
    ELSE (SELECT somevalue_1
          FROM someothertable_1
               JOIN ... 
               JOIN ...  
          WHERE something=something)
  END as Your_Result_ColumnName_1,

  CASE
    WHEN Appr_ID IS NULL THEN (
      SELECT somevalue_2
      FROM sometable_2
           JOIN ... 
           JOIN ... 
      WHERE something=something)
    ELSE (SELECT somevalue_2
          FROM someothertable_2
               JOIN ... 
               JOIN ...  
          WHERE something=something)
  END as Your_Result_ColumnName_2,

  ...

FROM
  YourTableWithApprIDInIt
```

Or

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN a.Appr_ID IS NULL THEN b.somevalue_1 
    ELSE c.somevalue_1
  END as Your_Result_ColumnName_1,

  CASE
    WHEN a.Appr_ID IS NULL THEN b.somevalue_2
    ELSE c.somevalue_2
  END as Your_Result_ColumnName_2,

  ...

FROM
  YourTableWithApprIDInIt a
  JOIN sometable b ON a.x = b.x
  JOIN ... ON ..

  JOIN someothertable c ON a.x = c.x
  JOIN ... ON ..
```

This is when the join syntax is really starting to look cleaner... But again, if each of your `Your_Result_ColumnName_X`s are coming from different tables, and each of these subqueries doesn't depend on values from inside your main outer query (such that each only needs to be evaluated only one time), the first of the two patterns *may* be more efficient even though it doesn't look cleaner ;-)

But again, test both in your specific scenario to see if there's a difference, and it may be that they're evaluated/optimised/executed by the DBMS to be exaclty same (in which case, choose the syntax pattern that makes most sense to you!) :-)

Comment: Thanks for your idea. But I've a problem to use it. The Select query used inside a Case will have to return me more than one column. So how to get more than one column from a single case statement. Please advise. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Can you post the other tables and what data you will get from them depending on whether Appr_id is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `CASE WHEN` Statement

```
SELECT 
 CASE 
   WHEN a.Appr_ID IS NULL THEN  b.somevalue
   ELSE c.somevalue
 END AS ResultColumn

INNER JOIN TABLE b ON a.somecolumn = b.somecolumn
INNER JOIN TABLE c ON a.somecolumn = c.somecolumn
```